# Change button press color in Dialog Fragment?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I want to change the color of button press in a dialog like in the image below.

[image]

I managed to accomplish this when using simple Alert Dialog.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

// Set dialog title
builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#8b0000'>"
                + getResources().getString(R.string.delete_this_list)
                + "?" + "</font>"));

builder.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.delete)
                + " '"
                + lists[listNo]
                + "'?\n"
                + getResources().getString(
                        R.string.delete_this_list_description))
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton(getResources().getString(R.string.delete),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.dismiss();

                        //Some background stuff
                        //.......//
                    }
                })
        .setNegativeButton(
                getResources().getString(android.R.string.cancel),
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
alertDialog = builder.create();
alertDialog.show();

alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
                .setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_bar_holo_red));
alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE)
            .setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_bar_holo_red));
```

But, this approach does not work when using DialogFragments.
When using DialogFragments, there is no getButton method.

Any ideas??

Comment: You do realize that AlertDialog will dismiss the dialog after a button has been clicked right?

Comment: Yeah i know that ... What i am saying is that the above code works with AlertDialog, but not with Dialog Fragments. Since DialogFragment returns a Dialog, i cannot use getButton() method because that method is of AlertDialog. Hope i am clear

Comment: how is actually changed title color and title separator line in your screenshot?

Comment: @Ewoks Used HoloEverywhere library in that project. Then to change the seperator line color, create a style:
<style name="RedAlertDialog" parent="Holo.Theme.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="alertDialogTitleDividerColor">@color/holo_red</item>
</style>    ... then add the above style in your theme:
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@style/Holo.Theme">
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/RedAlertDialog</item>
</style>

Comment: @Ewoks For the title text color, builder.setTitle(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#8b0000'>Dialog title</font>"));

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of:

> alertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE)
>                   .**setBackground**(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.btn_bar_holo_red));

Try:

```
alertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        Button positiveButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog)
              .getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        positiveButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bar_holo_red_full);

        Button negativeButton = ((AlertDialog) dialog)
              .getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE);
        negativeButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_bar_holo_red_full);
    }
});
```

Where btn_bar_holo_red_full would be defined in it's own xml file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_focused" android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button_default" />
</selector>
```

Then define button_pressed, button_focused and button_default as follows (you'll need three, one each for pressed, focused and default):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" androuid:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@color/btn_background_pressed" />
</shape>
```

All that's left to do is to add those color values to your color.xml file.